# How to run a angularjs project in eclipse?

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, http, server, editor

I am using [angularjs-eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angularjs-eclipse) tool of eclipse to use angularjs with eclipse .I have import the project and convert into angularjs project .

But now problem is that how to run this with a HTTP server ? Can someone please tell me what all the steps to run this project from eclipse ?

I tried to google/stackoverflow etc. to find the solution but i am not able to get a proper  or working solution for this.

When i will select project->RightClicked i am not getting Run On Server option Please check below is the project structure

[image]

Comment: You will have to add this project to a server and start the server, then open a browser and hit the URL. I am not sure if you are expecting this to do it through eclipse or ?

Comment: @CrazyMac I am not getting any option to add project into the server for any Java web project this option will automatically come(Add to server/Run on Server),but in this project i am missing all these options.

Comment: I have a similar project and I am able to run this through Tomcat. You dont see an option to 'Run on server' or 'Add or Remove' in the server section

Comment: @CrazyMac Yes i am not getting both the option even i configured Tomcat Server.

Comment: Please can you share the project structure ?

Comment: Under the project facets, try to check 'Dynamic web module' and try to run on server

Comment: @CrazyMac Added Project structure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140033/discussion-between-subodh-joshi-and-crazymac).